# How can I show all the questions I closed as duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I hold the gold badge of [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas). I can flag a post with this tag as a duplicate and close it immediately. Is there any way to view all of them?

I checked the [All actions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10315163/ynjxsjmh?tab=activity&sort=all) page where I found lists of my comments, edits, reviews, etc. except my duplicate flags. Also the [helpful flags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/10315163) page doesn't list this.

Comment: Users with close vote privilege cannot flag for closure anymore, instead they have to vote for closure. All close votes cast by the user are listed on `?tab=votes&sort=closure`, but that page cannot filter by close vote types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the SEDE query [My dupehammered close votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1634966) by [Spevacus](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/39347), which will list all the questions you've closed as duplicate with a gold tag badge (hammered). Note that SEDE will not show you questions that have been deleted.

If you want to find all the questions that you've closed as duplicate with a gold tag badge, including deleted questions, you can use the `?tab=votes&sort=closure` page in your profile, as [Andrew T.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2821954) mentioned in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421508/how-to-show-all-the-questions-i-closed-as-duplicate#comment934276_421508). However, this page lists *all* your close votes, so you will have to manually go through the list to find the ones you hammered as a duplicate.

Comment: Just as a general note, users who have not earned the privilege to [see deleted posts](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) will not be able to view close votes that they cast on questions which are now deleted as they will not appear in the list of votes in their profile. (This would not impact gold tag-badge holders since the requirement to earn a gold tag badge would also require having at least 10,000 reputation, but it may affect other users looking to audit their close vote history)

Answer (score 3):

If they're going to copy/re-use/adapt my query, at least take one that was updated to use newer features of SQL Server. Here is the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1672557?UserId=10315163) that uses OpenJson to decipher the Json blob that is present in the Text column of the PostHistory table for PostHistoryTypeId = 10. The Comment field holds the close reason, which is 101 for the Duplicates you're interested in.

```
-- userid: your user id on the site "found in the url of your profile"

declare @userid int = ##userid:int##

select postid [Post Link]
     , creationdate [Closing complete date]
     , Goldtagbadge [Badge]
from posthistory
cross apply openjson(text, '$.Voters') 
    with (Id int  '$.Id',
    GoldTagBadge nvarchar(50) '$.BindingReason.GoldTagBadge'
         ) as voters
where posthistorytypeid = 10
and voters.Id = @userid
and comment = 101
and Goldtagbadge is not null
```

When run today this is what the result looks like for your account:

[image: result set of query]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Hey this OpenJson stuff is pretty neat, and I wasn't aware of it (Not the biggest SQL person...) otherwise I would have used it in my version of your query (mentioned in [cigien's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421510/11171084)) from [way back when](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234057/622284).